# In flutter, how to set spacing between row items inside of a column?

Tags: flutter, row

I create many `Row` items that contain inside of a `Column` and want to make spacing between each row items. I tried to set with `mainAxisAlignment` of `Column`. But nothing changes between each `Row` items. How to change or which widget I need to use for that?

```
Column(
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                    child: Container(child: kTextFieldLabelText('Name:')),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 6,
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    child: Container(
                      //width: 100,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                        kTextFormFieldsDecoration('Enter your name'),
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                    child: Container(child: kTextFieldLabelText('Name:')),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 6,
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    child: Container(
                      //width: 100,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                        kTextFormFieldsDecoration('Enter your name'),
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 2,
                    fit: FlexFit.tight,
                    child: Container(child: kTextFieldLabelText('Name:')),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 6,
                    fit: FlexFit.loose,
                    child: Container(
                      //width: 100,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration:
                        kTextFormFieldsDecoration('Enter your name'),
                        maxLines: 1,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use also

```
Spacer(), or Spacer(flex: 1),
```

or use sized box determine your preferred height and width

```
SizedBox(height: // put here,),
```

and also sized box have other things like

```
   SizedBox.expand(),
```

either ways play with it

Comment: If I want a lot of ``row`` items, then I think I need to used a lot of ```SizedBox()``` 
 or ```Spacer()``` manually... That is so wired to do this.. Btw thanks for answers and that is work.

Answer (score 1):

If the `children` of the `Row` are of fixed size then you can use `MainAxisAlignment` for `Row` in order to arrange them accordingly.

Else if you have `widgets` that are `Flexible` then you may need to add a `SizedBox` with the required `width` between two widgets.

Comment: Ok. your explanation is also clear for me.